# Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in local-developer-group while running spring-boot-cli

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to follow the instruction on how to run a Spring application from command line: [getting-started-cli-example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html#getting-started-cli-example). After I run the application by entering `spring run app.groovy` I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>spring run app.groovy
startup failed:
General error during conversion: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The fo
llowing artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUIL
D-SNAPSHOT, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not fin
d artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in local-developer-
group (http://192.168.10.245:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)

org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.DependencyResolutionFailedException: org.eclipse.aether.
resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springf
ramework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-sta
rter-web:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-star
ter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in local-developer-group (http://192.168.10.245:8081/nexus/content/grou
ps/public)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:322)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:127)
        at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167)
        at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.GroovyCompiler.compile(GroovyCompiler.java:205)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compile(SpringApplicationRunner.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compileAndRun(SpringApplicationRunner.java:101)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.RunCommand$RunOptionHandler.run(RunCommand.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts coul
d not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, org.spring
framework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springf
ramework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in local-developer-group (http://192.168.
10.245:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:317)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could
not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, org.springfr
amework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springfra
mework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in local-developer-group (http://192.168.10
.245:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.spring
framework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in local-developer-group (http://192.168
.10.245:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

1 error
```

I tried to change the local-developer-group url in settings.xml of my maven installation to `http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/` since the error report clearly says the required artifact cannot be found, but still I got the the same error. It seems the spring-boot-cli doesn't use the settings of my maven installation. But I couldn't think of another place where this url can be specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use the release version of spring-boot-cli instead of the cutting edge snapshot version: [Manual installation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-manual-cli-installation).
2. The maven settings.xml spring-boot-cli uses is located in the `.m2` directory.